# Android SDK configuration with Titanium 3.01 on MAC (mavericks)

Tags: android, macos, titanium, appcelerator, android-2.2-froyo

Hi I am having a strange problem while configuring my android SDK with Titanium.I installed Titanium initially and configured SDK it was working well but then updated my MAC OS to mavericks and also updated Titanium Studio to 3.0.1. Unfortunately android SDK is now being show as not configured.Please help if anyone have better idea of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why Titanium SDk 3.01

Comment: can you post the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link :-

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix/

and upgrade your Titanium Studio and SDK configuration according to "**Titanium Compatibility Matrix**" for your MAC OS.

Comment: Titanium Compatibility Matrix made my solution Actually what I did is just updated my Titanium studio to latest version and also Node and CLI and then configured the android the same way and it worked.